# Copy database to tethered client

Tags: delphi, sqlite

I have created a tethered app. The server needs to copy a Sqlite db
and stream it to the client.

I get the db with this code:

```
procedure TfmxServer.actStreamTheDbExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := tmemorystream.Create;
  ms := dmplanner.GetDbAsStream;  // get it from the datamodule
  ms.Position := 0;
  thrprofServer.SendStream(thrmanServer.RemoteProfiles.First,
          'Stream_TheDB', ms);  // send it to the client
end;


function TdmPlanner.GetDbAsStream: TMemoryStream;  // datamodule
var
  fs: TFilestream;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  fs := tfilestream.Create(consqlite.Params.Values['Database'] , fmOpenRead);
  ms := tmemorystream.Create;
  try
   ms.loadfromstream(fs); // ms.size = 315392, file size = (315,392 bytes
   result := ms;               // so I am getting the full db3 file.
   result.Position := 0;
  finally
   freeandnil(fs);
   freeandnil(ms); // does this kill the result?
  end;
end;
```

I catch the stream and to write the db with this code:

```
procedure TfrmMobile_Client_Main.DoStreamTheDb(
  const Aresource: TremoteResource);
var
  fs: TFilestream;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  fs := tfilestream.Create
    (dmplannerclient.consqlite.Params.Values['Database'] ,
    fmopenreadwrite or fmCreate);
  try
   ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
   ms := TMemoryStream(AResource.Value.AsStream);
   ms.Position := 0;    // ms.size = 315392, so I got the whole file.
   ms.SaveToStream(fs);
  dmPlannerClient.FillLbx(lbxRecipeNames);
  // now fill a listbox, but when I open a query, I get
  //  [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: unable to open database file.
  finally
   freeandnil(fs);
   freeandnil(ms);
  end;
end;
```

So my question is, How do I copy the db to the client
and then use it on the client?

Better yet, How do I an in-memory db instead of an on-disk db?
I have tried setting the FDConnection filename to :memory: but that
did not work.

Delphi CE Rio 10.3.2

Thanks...Dan'l' +

Comment: In-memory db?  Use TFDMemTable.

Comment: This will be a static db. Read only.

Comment: Sorry, my comment about using an FDMemTable wasn't very helpful if you need the entire database copying to the client.  See my answer ...

Comment: Likely faster to transfer a compressed copy of the database file than making database calls to clone/duplicate a database over a network connection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't *think* there is a way to copy a Sqlite database in its entirety to a tethered
client short of copying the entire database file to the client, because it may contain
numerous tables and other resources like views, stored procs, etc.

However, copying the entire database as a file is actually quite
simple to do.  In the client, you can open a table in it using a local FDConnection
and FDQuery.

Server code:

```
procedure TApp1Form.SendDBAsStream;
var
  StreamToSend : TMemoryStream;

const
  DBName = 'D:\Delphi\Code\Sqlite\DB1.Sqlite';

begin
  StreamToSend := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StreamToSend.LoadFromFile(DBName);
    StreamToSend.Position := 0;
    TetheringAppProfile1.Resources.FindByName('SqliteDB').Value := StreamToSend;
  finally
    // Don't free StreamToSend ?
  end;
end;
```

Client code

```
procedure TApp2Form.TetheringAppProfile1Resources0ResourceReceived(const Sender:
    TObject; const AResource: TRemoteResource);
var
  ReceivedStream : TStream;
  FileStream : TFileStream;
begin
  FileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Temp.Sqlite';
  AResource.Value.AsStream.Position := 0;

  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  ReceivedStream := AResource.Value.AsStream;
  try
    ReceivedStream.Position := 0;
    FileStream.CopyFrom(ReceivedStream, ReceivedStream.Size);
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
    //  ReceivedStream.Free;  No!  The tethering framework frees the stream
  end;
  OpenTable;
end;

 procedure TApp2Form.OpenTable;
 begin
   if FDConnection1.Connected then
     FDConnection1.Connected := False;
   FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
   FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database=' + FileName);
   FDConnection1.DriverName := 'Sqlite';

   try
     FDConnection1.Connected := True;
     FDQuery1.Open('select * from mytable');
   except
     ShowMessage(Exception(ExceptObject).Message + ' ' + FileName);
   end;
 end;
```

I tested the above in Delphi 10.2.3 on Win10 64-bit and it works fine for me.

If you wanted to copy only a few tables to the client, what I would do is

- In the server, open one of the tables in an FDQuery, then assign its data to an
  FDMemtable by `FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery1.Data`
- Call SaveToStream on FDMemTable1 and send the stream as a stream resource to the client
- On the client, call FDMemTable.LoadFromStream to load the received stream.  I *think*,
  because I haven't tried it that the client would need to contain a TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink
  to support loading from the stream.

Comment: Did you try my code, and did it do what you want?  Sorry, there is a minor correction, namely the call to ReceivedStream.Free should be omitted.